# Serialization error in Scala

Tags: java, scala, serialization, sbt

You can safely skip to **EDIT2**.

Original question:

I thought Scala case classes were serializable out-of-box. Apparently not:

```
[error] (run-main-0) java.lang.ClassCastException: cannot assign instance of scala.collection.immutable.List$SerializationProxy to field x.y.a.common.LibraryTest$SerializationTest$Doggies.oldDoggies of type scala.collection.immutable.List in instance of x.y.a.common.LibraryTest$SerializationTest$Doggies
java.lang.ClassCastException: cannot assign instance of scala.collection.immutable.List$SerializationProxy to field x.y.a.common.LibraryTest$SerializationTest$Doggies.oldDoggies of type scala.collection.immutable.List in instance of x.y.a.common.LibraryTest$SerializationTest$Doggies
    at java.io.ObjectStreamClass$FieldReflector.setObjFieldValues(ObjectStreamClass.java:2089)
    at java.io.ObjectStreamClass.setObjFieldValues(ObjectStreamClass.java:1261)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.defaultReadFields(ObjectInputStream.java:2006)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readSerialData(ObjectInputStream.java:1924)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:1801)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1351)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject(ObjectInputStream.java:371)
    at x.y.a.common.LibraryTest$SerializationTest$.run(LibraryTest.scala:144)
    at x.y.a.common.LibraryTest$$anonfun$runTests$1.apply(LibraryTest.scala:23)
    at x.y.a.common.LibraryTest$$anonfun$runTests$1.apply(LibraryTest.scala:21)
    at scala.collection.immutable.List.foreach(List.scala:381)
    at x.y.a.common.LibraryTest$.runTests(LibraryTest.scala:21)
    at x.y.b.server.game.GameServerLauncher$.launch(GameServerLauncher.scala:15)
    at x.y.b.server.common.CommonServerLauncher$.delayedEndpoint$x$y$b$server$common$CommonServerLauncher$1(CommonServerLauncher.scala:8)
    at x.y.b.server.common.CommonServerLauncher$delayedInit$body.apply(CommonServerLauncher.scala:6)
    at scala.Function0$class.apply$mcV$sp(Function0.scala:34)
    at scala.runtime.AbstractFunction0.apply$mcV$sp(AbstractFunction0.scala:12)
    at scala.App$$anonfun$main$1.apply(App.scala:76)
    at scala.App$$anonfun$main$1.apply(App.scala:76)
    at scala.collection.immutable.List.foreach(List.scala:381)
    at scala.collection.generic.TraversableForwarder$class.foreach(TraversableForwarder.scala:35)
    at scala.App$class.main(App.scala:76)
    at x.y.b.server.common.CommonServerLauncher$.main(CommonServerLauncher.scala:6)
    at x.y.b.server.common.CommonServerLauncher.main(CommonServerLauncher.scala)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
```

Here is the relevant test code (`LibraryTestRunner` is just a trait without implementation):

```scala
  object SerializationTest extends LibraryTestRunner {
    override def name: String = "Serialization"

    case class Pupper(name: String)

    case class Doggies(oldDoggies: List[Pupper], master: HeroRef)

    override def run(): String = {
      def createDoggies = Doggies(List(Pupper("Adolf"), Pupper("Ben")), HeroRef(49))
      val input = createDoggies

      val data = {
        val bos = new ByteArrayOutputStream()
        val out = new ObjectOutputStream(bos)
        out.writeObject(input)
        val r = bos.toByteArray
        out.close()
        bos.close()
        r
      }
      val readObject = {
        val bis = new ByteArrayInputStream(data)
        val in = new ObjectInputStream(bis)
        val r = in.readObject()
        bis.close()
        in.close()
        r
      }
      readObject.toString
    }
  }
```

Scala version is 2.11.7 and it is compiled and run via SBT. I also tried `Seq` instead of `List`, it crashed in a same way.

PS: Please excuse incorrect usage of terms `doggy` and `pupper`, I was changing the code over and over and in the process the meaning broke...

---

**EDIT1**:
Here is `LibraryTestRunner`:

```
  trait LibraryTestRunner {
    def name: String

    def run(): String
  }
```

It was originally a class, but the transition didn't change anything.

I tested it with Gradle (client side of libGDX project) and it works, I have no idea, why it crashes on a server side compiled with SBT. Scala versions are same and code is identical (linked through NTFS junction).

Here is a snippet from `build.sbt`, because I can't think of anything else that differs in those two situations.

```
libraryDependencies ++= Seq(
  "io.netty" % "netty-all" % "4.1.0.Beta8",
  "com.badlogicgames.gdx" % "gdx" % "1.7.0",
  "org.scalaz" %% "scalaz-core" % "7.2.0",

  "com.github.julien-truffaut" %% "monocle-core" % monocleVersion,
  "com.github.julien-truffaut" %% "monocle-generic" % monocleVersion,
  "com.github.julien-truffaut" %% "monocle-macro" % monocleVersion,
  "com.github.julien-truffaut" %% "monocle-state" % monocleVersion,
  "com.github.julien-truffaut" %% "monocle-refined" % monocleVersion,
  "com.github.julien-truffaut" %% "monocle-law" % monocleVersion % "test",

  "org.scalactic" %% "scalactic" % "2.2.6",
  "org.scalatest" %% "scalatest" % "2.2.6" % "test",

  "com.typesafe.akka" %% "akka-actor" % "2.4.2",

  "bsf" % "bsf" % "2.4.0"
)

addCompilerPlugin("org.scalamacros" %% "paradise" % "2.1.0" cross CrossVersion.full)
```

I'll try reproduce the error in minimal environment.

---

**EDIT2**:

Here is the minimal not-working code:

```scala
import java.io.{ByteArrayInputStream, ByteArrayOutputStream, ObjectInputStream, ObjectOutputStream}

object Main extends App {
  SerializationTest.run()
}

case class IntSeqHolder(seq: Seq[Int])

case class Pupper(name: String)

case class Doggies(oldPuppers: Seq[Pupper])

object SerializationTest {

  def run() {
    Seq(
      Seq(1),
      IntSeqHolder(Seq(1)),
      Doggies(Seq(Pupper("Adolf"), Pupper("Ben")))
    ).foreach { x =>
      val res = test(x)
      println(s"$x ==> $res")
      assert(x == res)
    }
  }

  def test(input: AnyRef): AnyRef = {
    val data = {
      val bos = new ByteArrayOutputStream()
      val out = new ObjectOutputStream(bos)
      out.writeObject(input)
      val r = bos.toByteArray
      out.close()
      bos.close()
      r
    }
    val readObject = {
      val bis = new ByteArrayInputStream(data)
      val in = new ObjectInputStream(bis)
      val r = in.readObject()
      in.close()
      bis.close()
      r
    }
    readObject
  }
}
```

`build.sbt`:

```
name := "serialization_test"

version := "1.0"

scalaVersion := "2.11.7"
```

Output of `sbt run`:

```
List(1) ==> List(1)
IntSeqHolder(List(1)) ==> IntSeqHolder(List(1))
[error] (run-main-0) java.lang.ClassCastException: cannot assign instance of scala.collection.immutable.List$SerializationProxy to field Doggies.oldPuppers of type scala.collection.Seq in instance of Doggies
java.lang.ClassCastException: cannot assign instance of scala.collection.immutable.List$SerializationProxy to field Doggies.oldPuppers of type scala.collection.Seq in instance of Doggies
        at java.io.ObjectStreamClass$FieldReflector.setObjFieldValues(ObjectStreamClass.java:2089)
        at java.io.ObjectStreamClass.setObjFieldValues(ObjectStreamClass.java:1261)
        at java.io.ObjectInputStream.defaultReadFields(ObjectInputStream.java:2006)
        at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readSerialData(ObjectInputStream.java:1924)
        at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:1801)
        at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1351)
        at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject(ObjectInputStream.java:371)
        at SerializationTest$.test(SerializationTest.scala:41)
        at SerializationTest$$anonfun$run$1.apply(SerializationTest.scala:22)
        at SerializationTest$$anonfun$run$1.apply(SerializationTest.scala:21)
        at scala.collection.immutable.List.foreach(List.scala:381)
        at SerializationTest$.run(SerializationTest.scala:21)
        at Main$.delayedEndpoint$Main$1(SerializationTest.scala:4)
        at Main$delayedInit$body.apply(SerializationTest.scala:3)
        at scala.Function0$class.apply$mcV$sp(Function0.scala:34)
        at scala.runtime.AbstractFunction0.apply$mcV$sp(AbstractFunction0.scala:12)
        at scala.App$$anonfun$main$1.apply(App.scala:76)
        at scala.App$$anonfun$main$1.apply(App.scala:76)
        at scala.collection.immutable.List.foreach(List.scala:381)
        at scala.collection.generic.TraversableForwarder$class.foreach(TraversableForwarder.scala:35)
        at scala.App$class.main(App.scala:76)
        at Main$.main(SerializationTest.scala:3)
        at Main.main(SerializationTest.scala)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
```

Interestingly `Seq` in `IntSeqHolder` deserializes fine, possibly because of the primitive inside? I also tried it on `Seq(Pupper("Collin"))` and it crashed on `java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Pupper` o_O. I am very confused.

Comment: your code works for me... I have a feeling the issue is with `LibraryTestRunner` - since the case classes are defined within the object that extends it, it might be serialized too. Does that trait extend any other trait with actual implementation?

Comment: @TzachZohar Thank you for your time. And no, the trait does not extend anything. I have updated the question.